# Screen sharing stops working after disconnecting for about five minutes

Tags: remote-desktop

I'm running macOS Mojave on a Mac Mini. Built-in VNC server works perfectly when you connect for the first time after reboot, however if you disconnect from it for more than five minutes you can't connect again - it displays the username that was used for the last session and a spinning wheel. Connecting via ssh and killing screensharingagentd doesn't help, only a reboot does. I've verified all the power saving settings are off. There are two virtual machines with macOS High Sierra and Sierra running on this same Mac Mini and I can connect to them without any issues.

Comment: I'm experiencing this too (MBP 2016 with up-to-date Mojave), but have so far been unable to determine the cause of find a workaround other than reboot. What VNC client are you using? I'm using VNC Viewer on iPhone. Just wondering if we're using the same app in case it might be triggering a bad state on macOS.

Comment: Also happening from Win 10 desktop with VNC Viewer 6.18.907 (r38355) x64
I doubt it is the client as previous version of macOS worked fine

Comment: Hah! Just updated to macOS 10.14.1 hoping it would resolve the issue - now I can't connect via VNC Viewer at all!

Comment: I too am experiencing this ever since I upgraded to Mojave. So frustrating. I am going to try TeamViewer, see if that helps.

Comment: Same problem here. The problem also started after updates. Dealing with a relatively new macbook pro. Client is realvnc viewer 6.17.1113.

Answer (score 10):

My workaround for this problem is to login via ssh and kill loginwindow process:

```
sudo pkill loginwindow
```

This will allow to login via VNC then.

Comment: This works for us; however we do have to reconnect with TightVNC when it gets into this state.

Answer (score 2):

With the iMac at work, we had to turn OFF the option under `System Preferences - Sharing - Screen Sharing - Computer Settings` to allow `VNC viewers may control screen with password`. Then [VNC Viewer](https://www.realvnc.com/en/connect/download/viewer/) prompts for the username & password of the iMac (assuming `Only these users:` is selected for `Allow access for`). Multiple connections work fine with that setting disabled. Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried turning off that option, and ensured the "allow access for" list includes my user.  I then get an error message when attempting to connect via VNC 

"To connect to Apple Remote Desktop (10.4) or Screen Sharing/Remote Management (10.5 onwards) built-in to Mac OS X, turn on the "VNC viewers may control screen with password" option

Comment: Sorry, @softwareevolved I no longer have access to a Mac to help any further. Hopefully someone else can follow this up for you.

Answer (score 1):

From [this article](https://help.realvnc.com/hc/en-us/articles/360016134372-Remote-access-to-macOS-10-14-Mojave-is-view-only-until-access-is-granted-locally-to-the-vncagent-application):

> Apple have added a new security layer to macOS 10.14 Mojave. After upgrading your Mac to Mojave, VNC Server will allow only view-only remote access until such time as you've granted access to the vncagent application (installed as part of VNC Server).
>
> To do this, open System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Privacy > Accessibility. Click the lock button to make changes, and + to add a new app to the list allowed to control your computer. Navigate to `/Library/vnc/vncagent` and select the Open button

Answer (score 0):

Some more detail, as I'm seeing very similar behaviour, possibly the same.

Using RealVNC client connecting to RealVNC server on Mojave, works perfectly every time. Using this method you are connecting via the cloud using RealVNC to negotiate a session.

Using RealVNC client connecting to Macs own "ScreenShare" utility, via bonjour or local IP address, does not use the RealVNC server, and works for the first few attempts, but leave it for 5 minutes without logging in, then try again and it fails exactly as described, Lockscreen with User's name and picture, but a spinning wheel beneath, with no option to login.

Reconnecting via RealVNC server is still possible whilst in this state.

Stopping and starting ScreenSharing only kills the window with the spinning wheel, it has no other effect.

A reboot of the MAC, and it works again....for a while.

Worked fine on High Sierra.

Comment: Hi, Paul, and welcome to Apple StackExchange! Since this post actually describes the problem further, but doesn't _answer_ it, this isn't really an Answer. Instead, feel free to add it to the question by pressing the *improve this question* link just beneath it.

Answer (score 0):

Not a fix, but another work-around to clear the locked spinny screen is to access the mac (physically) and log out the user.  My Mini is in a server closet, close to my desk, so this is annoying but not too difficult.

(I am going to try the option above to tinker with the connection/login)

Answer (score 0):

Apologies that this is as an answer but I lack enough reputation to add it as a comment.

I had exactly the same issue so I took to contacting Apple for support.  After a lot of back and forth trying to explain the issue I was eventually given this response.

> Apple Support
>
> So, regarding this specific setup, this is something outside of normal
>   consumer support that we can assist with. I can, however get you in
>   contact with our business department who works with remote server
>   access and can help provide you with more details moving forward. For
>   those steps, this would require contacting our phone support. Would
>   you like for me to schedule a time for you, or would you prefer the
>   phone number to get in contact with them at your leisure?
>
> Me
>
> Give me the number and I'll see when I can get a call
>   done.
>
> Apple Support
>
> Sure thing - here is the main AppleCare support number:
>   1-800-275-2273 I will also email you our case number as well. When you
>   contact them, you can let them know that you are looking to speak with
>   our business support team regarding a remote server issue, and they
>   will get you route you to the right place.
>
> Me
>
> and so we're totally clear remote screen sharing is not
>   supported for normal users only for businesses?
>
> Apple Support
>
> That is correct

So from that if you are an end user who isn't prepared to go through business support good luck.

Comment: This rather reads like there was some confusion about "remote server access" and "screen sharing". Screen sharing is a standard macOS functionality and definitively not something the user support shouldn't be able to handle.

Comment: I agree it shouldn't. This was after I was elevated through to 2nd tier support and after they had blamed all the other VNC clients I had tried at the other end so they knew it was a VNC issue.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a Mojave bug.

The suggested `sudo pkill loginwindow` work-around will logout the current user on the machine and kill all it's processes.

A better option is given in [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/354294/14586) to [another question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/342161/14586) about the same problem:

```
sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.RemoteManagement VNCAlwaysStartOnConsole -bool true
```

It takes effect immediately (without reboot), and lets you connect directly to the current session, with only the VNC password.