# How can I stop VNC/Remote access freeze without rebooting or logging out current user?

Tags: remote-desktop, screen-sharing

I have several macs that I login to remotely periodically and sometimes the login will hang and display a spinning wheel. Currently, I have to ssh to the system and run sudo pkill loginwindow which also logs out other users.  I would like to avoid interrupting anything currently running but still be able to log in via VNC.

The other solutions have suggested removing authentication which I would prefer not to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution which works for me.

TL;DR:
use `sudo pkill -9 -u 0 -fx '/System/Library/CoreServices/loginwindow.app/Contents/MacOS/loginwindow'` instead of `sudo pkill loginwindow`

I originally used the answer from [MacOS Mojave remote access login screen stuck on infinite loading spinner](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/342161/macos-mojave-remote-access-login-screen-stuck-on-infinite-loading-spinner) but logging out everything became a problem.  I ran `pgrep loginwindow` and found I was killing two processes.

`ps -f` on those two PIDs gave me:

> UID PID PPID C STIME TTY TIME CMD
> XXX  XXX     1   0 11:28PM ??         0:06.58 /System/Library/CoreServices/loginwindow.app/Contents/MacOS/loginwindow console
> 0  XXX   XXX   0  5:47PM ??         0:00.21 /System/Library/CoreServices/loginwindow.app/Contents/MacOS/loginwindow

Killing the nonconsole process allowed the VNC connection to succeed with no spinning wheel.

My new process is:

1. Close VNC/Screen Sharing Window
2. Connect via ssh: `ssh user@host`
3. Run `sudo pkill -9 -u 0 -fx '/System/Library/CoreServices/loginwindow.app/Contents/MacOS/loginwindow'`
4. Connect using VNC as usual